# How can I cache in firebase-function while building your API

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am cloud firestore as Database, also building my own API, I want to cache data and i was able to found this `res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=300, s-maxage=600');` now my problem is this:

If I have an endpoint with `route` `/allmydata` and I cache the data which contain:

```
{
"data":[
"name":"john doe",
"name":"john",
],
}
```

then I have another endpoint with `route /checkdata/:name` then I want to get the cache data and perform a query on that data cache. How will I do that?

I have try to use [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) but it set the data in route "/allmydata" but for me to use that data in "/checkdata/:name" endpoint is not working..

Comment: I would highly recommend contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact) to help you further in this concern.